# Area of ​the rotation surface generated by a parametric curve around the Z axis

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, surfaces

I know it might seem like a trivial question but I honestly couldn't find this formula anywhere.
If I have
$$\Gamma(t)=(x(t),y(t),z(t))\qquad t\in[a,b]$$
I want to calculate the area of ​​the rotation surface generated by a parametric curve around the $Z$ axis.

### My process

The rotation surface has this equation:
$$\Gamma(t)=\begin{pmatrix}x(t)\\y(t)\\z(t)\end{pmatrix}\mapsto \Gamma_R(u,v)=
\begin{pmatrix}x(u)\cos(v)-y(u)\sin(v)\\
x(u)\sin(v)+y(u)\cos(v)\\
z(u)\end{pmatrix}\qquad u\in[a,b], v\in[0,2\pi]$$
$$A=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_a^b\left\Vert\frac{\partial\Gamma_R}{\partial u}\times\frac{\partial\Gamma_R}{\partial v}\right\Vert\mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}v$$
(Various calculations.... for brevity $x:=x(u), y:=y(u)$ and $z:=z(u)$)
$${A=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{a}^{b}\sqrt{\left(xx'-xy'\sin(2v)-yy'\cos(2v)\right)^{2}+z'^{2}\left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right)}\mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}v}$$
Is it possible to simplify this formula further? I would like to remove the dependence on $v$ and highlight a $\pi$ in front of the integral since these formulas generally have that form.

Comment: Let $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ to recover the classic setup.

Comment: @user10354138 Do you indents impose $r(t)=\sqrt{x(t)^2+y(t)^2}$?

Comment: Yes I do, putting everything back in cylindrical coordinates where it belongs (i.e., shifting $v$ to $v'=v-f(u)$ some $f$ so that $v'$ is the $\theta$ coordinates in cylindrical polars).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us define a curve $\gamma(t) = (x, y, z)(t)$. The area resulting surface around z-axis is given by formula
$$
\int\limits_{z_0}^{z_1} 2 \pi r \,ds
\overset{\substack{ds = \sqrt{r'(t)^2 + z'(t)^2}\,dt \\ r^2 = x^2 + y^2}}{=}
2 \pi \int\limits_{t_0}^{t_1} \sqrt{(x(t)^2 + y(t)^2)(r'(t)^2 + z'(t)^2)} \, dt.
$$

The radius derivative $r'(t)$ corresponds to formula $\frac{x'(t) x(t) + y(t) y'(t)}{\sqrt{x(t)^2 + y(t)^2}}$.

Comment: derp. Thanks! :-P

Comment: The $dz$ should be an arclength element? :) (Getting _that_ relies in turn on user10354138's comment.)

Comment: I really believe dz suits best here due Riemann integral construction. You may be right, this would complicate calculation though.

Comment: It's not a notational convention, but the distinction between lateral area of a cylinder (which doesn't given surface area in the limit) and lateral area of a frustum of a cone (which does give surface area)....

Comment: In both cases, the formula applies, doesn't it? On former, variable $r$ is constant, the other, r grows linearly such that $r = r_0 + \alpha t$.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I cannot understand your example. Please, may you reformulate?

Comment: If we write $r(t)=\sqrt{x(t)^2+y(t)^2}$, the "profile" of OP's surface is parametrized by $(r(t), 0, z(t))$; the arc length parameter along the profile is $$ds=\sqrt{r'(t)^2+z'(t)^2}\,dt,$$which is not $dz$ unless $r$ is constant (or $r$ happens to satisfy an ODE guaranteeing the surface is part of a unit sphere). The surface area is $2\pi\int_a^b r\, ds$, not $2\pi\int_a^b r\, dz$.

Comment: IIRC, my parenthetical remark about the ODE is wrong. It can happen that $r\,ds = dz$ under those conditions, but not $ds = dz$.

Comment: I agree. I will edit the answer.